# My select item in vue js is not displaying properly in browser and the component is not re-rendering

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to create a select form input in vueJs/Nuxt but the select is not displaying right in the browser, even though I have used v-model binding. I still get this error in the browser

> "Property or method "selected" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property"

Here's my code below:

```html
<select v-model="selected">
  <option value="Receipt">Receipt</option>
  <option>Invoice</option>
</select>
```

```js
data() {
  return {
    selected: 'receipt'
  }
}
```

Comment: The code excerpts look ok, but the problem cannot be determined with that alone. Can you show a complete example? or share a link to a reproduction?

Comment: You probably wanted to have `selected: 'Receipt',` (capital `R`) here. Also, I do agree with tony of the fact that just this works fine. Are you sure you did not have any other `selected` key somewhere? Do ESlint gives you any error at all? More code could help us here.